# How does php know when interpret and when to output?

Tags: javascript, php

I recently tried including JavaScript using PHP as such:

```
<?php include 'iife.SomeFile.js';?>
```

I did not expect it to work, b.c. I thought it would try to interpret the JS as PHP, but instead it just included the file as I asked it.

Is it b.c. I simply omitted the `<?php` tag that it chose to output the file as text.

Makes me wonder if I can include pretty much any type of file I want.

Also, makes the purpose of SSI seem redundant.

Comment: What's your question exactly? You kind of answered it yourself

Comment: I would wonder if he is asking if you included a .js file that did contain the <?php ?> tags, would it execute the PHP? But then, just try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP includes work the same way includes for languages such as C.  They simply include or insert the file at that point.

It's just like typing in that entire file yourself where you put the include.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a valid PHP file:

```
<html>
...
<script>
   var foo = 'bar';
</script>
```

You may notice that there's no PHP at all in this file, yet it's still valid. That's because PHP was designed as an embedded language to be used in HTML, **delimited by the `<?php ?>` tags.** PHP passes anything that's not in those tags through as is.

> Also, makes the purpose of SSI seem redundant.

The existence of one language does not make another redundant. Many languages overlap with many other languages in what they can do. Doesn't mean we should all be using just one language. For one, SSI is a lot more lightweight than a full-blown PHP instance if all you want is to include a file.

Comment: Yes, PHP starts and stops with every single request to your web server. Each individual request spawns a new PHP instance which is shut down at the end of the request.

Comment: Yes of course. I'm saying that if all you wanted to do was include a file like SSI, where PHP is completely irrelevant, then using SSI makes a lot more sense and you should not replace that with PHP, as you seemed to suggest.

Answer (score -1):

PHP code is executed on the server side. JavaScript is executed on the client side (except with node.js)

The include statement is used to include PHP code. You can use it to include a php lib file in your code.

Comment: `The include statement is used to include PHP code` You can include anything you want, I don't see the reason for this rule. Quite common for example is to include plain html, just to avoid tiresome copypasting when not using a template engine. And where or IF the code is executed is irrelevant here, if you include via php a js file it will be fully functional on the browser

Comment: You're right. You can include anything. But "The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file." (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) so, to my mind, include a js script with this statement is not the best way to proceed because the PHP engine  will parse your file (which do not contain any php code).